# Two tcp connections from a client in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

Im new to twisted. I have written a client which connects to a server on two ports 8037 and 8038. I understand that the factory creates two connection objects. Now when i press Ctrl-C, it says

```
Connection Lost Connection to the other side was lost in a non clean fashion.
Connection Lost Connection to the other side was lost in a non clean fashion.
```

Below is the code:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol,reactor

class TestClient(protocol.Protocol):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def connectionMade(self):
    print "Connected "
    self.sayHello()

  def connectionLost(self,reason):
    self.transport.loseConnection()

  def sayHello(self):
    self.transport.write("Hello")

  def dataReceived(self,data):
    print "Received data ",data



class TestClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
  def buildProtocol(self,addr):
    return TestClient()

  def clientConnectionFailed(self,connectory,reason):
    print "Connection Failed ",reason.getErrorMessage()

  def clientConnectionLost(self,connector,reason):
    print "Connection Lost ",reason.getErrorMessage()

reactor.connectTCP("<server_ip>",8037,TestClientFactory())
reactor.connectTCP("<server_ip>",8038,TestClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

1. How can i make the client close both tcp connections cleanly ?.
2. How to call the sayHello() method for only one connection ?

Im new to twisted, so an example would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected, if you want to call sayHello, you can use the thought of rpc.

For example, you send a message like 'sayHello_args', parse msg and call sayhello by args.

If you don't want to send any msg. When you connected, d.addCallback(sayHello) to call.
     `d = defer.succeed(0)
      d.addCallback(lambda _ : self.sayHello())`

And if you want to close connection, to use reactor.stop()

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply xiaohen. But the if condition in clientConnectionLost still gives me the connection closed in non clean fashion message.

Comment: i add a new picture by this way; I close cleanly. If you know another way to solve this problem, tell me please.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unclean connection shutdown is really nothing to worry about.  Getting a clean exit would potentially make your shutdown process slower and buggier because it requires a bunch of additional code, and you have to be able to deal with abnormal network connection termination no matter what.  In fact calling it "clean" is maybe even a bit misleading: "simultaneously confirmed" might be closer to what it's actually telling you about how the connection was closed.

As far as how to call `sayHello`, I don't fully understand your question, but if you use [AMP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/core/howto/amp.html), calling a method on the opposite side of the connection is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glyph. I have edited the code for TestClient above. Im calling self.sayHello() after a connection is made. What i mean by calling sayHello() for only one connection is that in the above code, after connection is established to the server on ports 8037 and 8038, the "Hello" message would be sent from the client on both the ports, right ?. Is there a way to send that message on only one port, either 8037 or 8038 ?. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  If you want the client connected to port 8038 to do something different than what `TestClientFactory` does, instantiate something other than `TestClientFactory`, or give `TestClientFactory` a constructor parameter that it passes along to `TestClient` to tell it to do something different.  But this has nothing to do with Twisted; if you want Python objects to do something different you just have to make different Python objects :)

Comment: Also, you should probably not use `connectTCP` directly. Use [Endpoints](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/core/howto/endpoints.html) instead.